# LINQ. Как сгруппировать List<T> по определенному элементу

Tags: c#, linq

Не могу понять как сгруппировать элементы в `List<T>` по определенному полю

Создается `List<GeneratedTag> tags` и заполняется объектами `GeneratedTag`:

```
public class GeneratedTag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public int ServerId { get; set; }
}
```

В итоге мне нужно "откинуть" объекты с повторяющимися `TagId` в `List`.
Решил сделать это с помощью `GroupBy`, т.к. думал что в итоге у меня будет список тех же элементов, но они не будут повторяться... Видимо это не так.

Попытался сделать так, но получаю какой-то непонятный `List`:

```
var tagsNew = tags.GroupBy(e => e.TagId)
    .Select(t => new { TagId = t.Key, tags = t.ToList() })
    .ToList();
```

Как сделать правильно?

Comment: @Grundy, да оно, спасибо